# Problem with passing context to enum Retrofit

Tags: android, enums, singleton, retrofit

I have created an enum singleton Retrofit class :

```
 public enum RetrofitClient {

    INSTANCE;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClientInitialization().build())
                .build();
    }

    public API callEndPoint() { return retrofit.create(API.class); }

    private OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientInitialization() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        //initialize the header
        retrofitHeader(httpClient);

        return httpClient;
    }

    private void retrofitHeader(OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient) {
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "secret-key")
                    .addHeader("lang", MyTools.getCurrentLanguage(context.getApplicationContext()));//ERORR
            return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
        });
    }
}
```

but the problem is how to pass context to use it with **getCurrentLanguage**
Is there's any way to do this ? without changing enum or any clean code ?

Answer (score 2):

The Application class in Android is the base class within an Android app that contains all other components such as activities and services.

Here's an example of RetrofitApiClient

```
 public class ApiClient {

        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.gaida.nepal.app/api/";
        private static File httpCacheDirectory = new File(AppApplication.getAppContext().getCacheDir(), "new_responses");
        private static int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        private static Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
        private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
        public static Retrofit getClient() {
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    //        builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
    //        builder.authenticator(new ApiTokenAuthenticator());
            OkHttpClient httpClient = builder
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    //                .addInterceptor(new ApiInterceptor())
                    .build();


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            RxJava2CallAdapterFactory rxJava2CallAdapterFactory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.computation());


            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
                        .client(httpClient)
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }

    }
```

Application Class

```
public class AppApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static AppApplication tourismApplication;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static boolean isActive;

    private Activity activity;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        tourismApplication = this;
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getAppContext());

    }


    public static AppApplication getInstance() {
        return tourismApplication;
    }


    public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return isActive;
    }


    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return tourismApplication.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreference() {
        return sharedPreferences;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        isActive = true;


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        isActive = true;


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        isActive = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        isActive = false;


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        isActive = false;


    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AppApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) AppApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
        activity.finish();
        System.exit(2);

    }
```

Declare Application Class in Manifest.xml like

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_logo_onn_app"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".helpers.AppApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
</application>
```

Now Get Application Context as

```
AppApplication.getAppContext()
```

RetrofitApi Interceptor

```
public class ApiInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        if (Utilities.getLoginResponse() == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(Utilities.getLoginUserToken())) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }


        Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", Utilities.getLoginUserToken())
                .addHeader("Accept", "Accept: application/x.school.v1+json")
                .header("Cache-Control", String.format("max-age=%d", 50000))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Example of getting selected language:

```
 public static String getSelectedLanguage() {
        return AppApplication.getSharedPreference().getString(AppConstants.SELECTED_LANGUAGE,"en");
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your comment 
but tell me do you thing if i pass Application to callEndPoint() on my code and pass application object to getCurrentLanguage() is better?? 
and sorry if i will take from time but can you explain me your code ? and why it's better

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh Its an approach for retrofit by documentation. And For your case use the interceptor and get selected language from shared preference and send it to the header. Answer Updated